How can I automatically sync data upsertion from SQLite to my Pinecone index?
I'm working on a project where I need to sync data from a SQLite database to a Pinecone index. I have two Python scripts: one to handle the SQLite database and another to set up and connect to Pinecone.
SQLite Database Script (database.py):
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

def create_db():
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('products_catalog.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            name TEXT NOT NULL,
            description TEXT NOT NULL,
            price REAL NOT NULL
        )
        ''')
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        print("Database created successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error creating database: {e}")

def load_csv_to_db(csv_path):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('products_catalog.db')
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
        df.to_sql('products', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        print("CSV data loaded successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading CSV data: {e}")

# Test the functions
if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_db()
    load_csv_to_db('D:/projectA/products_catalog.csv')


Pinecone Setup Script (pinecone_setup.py):
import os
import pandas as pd
from pinecone import Pinecone
from pinecone import ServerlessSpec
import time

# initialize connection to pinecone (get API key at app.pinecone.io)
api_key = os.getenv("PINECONE_API_KEY") or "my_pinecone_api_key_here"

# configure client
pc = Pinecone(api_key=api_key)

spec = ServerlessSpec(
    cloud="aws", region="us-east-1"
)

index_name = 'stfan'
existing_indexes = [
    index_info["name"] for index_info in pc.list_indexes()
]

# check if index already exists (it shouldn't if this is first time)
if index_name not in existing_indexes:
    # if does not exist, create index
    pc.create_index(
        index_name,
        dimension=1536,  # dimensionality of ada 002
        metric='dotproduct',
        spec=spec
    )
    # wait for index to be initialized
    while not pc.describe_index(index_name).status['ready']:
        time.sleep(1)

# connect to index
index = pc.Index(index_name)
time.sleep(1)

Questions:

What is the best practice for handling this data synchronization to avoid duplication and ensure consistency?
How can I implement a system to handle deletions and updates in the Pinecone index when records are modified in SQLite?

Additional Notes:
The dimensionality for Pinecone index is set to 1536.
I use dotproduct as the metric for similarity search.
